# Pixel and Tonix Assets and Wygwam Fields within Content Elements

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, wygwam, content-elements

I looked around and could not find how to have different types of Wygwam and Asset fields inside of Content Elements.

For example I want to be able to have two different types of Wygwam fields. I assumed my template would look like this:

```
{wygwam}
    {if element_name == "Address Content"}
        <div class="address-content">{value}</div>
    {if:else}
        {value}
    {/if}
{/wygwam}
```

This does not seem to work. Is this even possible at this point in time? Assets is giving me the same issue.

Any clarification would be awesome!

Thanks in advanced!

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap the element_name in quotes:

```
{if "{element_name}" == "Address Content"}
```

Comment: Thanks! No idea where I missed that in the documentation.